# Saving application/json with SLIM 3 and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, rest, eloquent, slim

So, when getting an Object from the database i do something like this in the Object Controller:

```
public function show(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{
    $id = (int)$args['oid'];
    $object = $this->object->getObjectById($id);       
    $data = $this->fractal->createData(new Item($object, new ObjectTransformer()))->toArray();      
    return $response->withJson($data);
}
```

I'm using fractal to transform the database structure to the needed JSON format and Eloquent for the Database access.

Then i'm getting something like this:

```
{
    "propertyId": 12345,
    "created": "2017-12-29T19:25:23+01:00",
    "modified": "2018-06-07T17:28:04+02:00",
    "published": true,
    "market": [
        "buy"
    ],
    "text": {
        "title": "Object Title"
    }
}
```

I'm sending the exact same JSON string (without the ID) via Postman as application/json.

When trying to save a new object i'm doing this in the Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, Response $response, array $args)
{       
   $object = new Object($request->getParsedBody());
   //dd($request->getParsedBody());
   $object->save(); // nothing happens, just an empty entry
}
```

The Object Class

```
class Object extends \Comp\Models\Mapper
{
    protected $database;

    protected $hidden = array('created_by', 'checked_out', 'checked_out_time', 'modified_by', 'access', 'params', 'oid', 'video');
    protected $casts = [
        'published' => 'boolean',
        'featured' => 'boolean',
        'rating' => 'float',
    ];
    protected $dates = ['created','modified'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    /*protected $fillable = [
        'shop_id','vendor_id','name','address','pincode','phone','shop_type'
    ];*/


    public function __construct( $database)
    {           
        $this->setTable('objects');
        $this->database = $database;
    }
}
```

The "Mapper" Class

```
<?php
namespace Comp\Models;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class Mapper extends Model {
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
    }

    public function removeEmptyElements(array $array)
    {

    }

}
```

I don't know if and how to do a transformation again, to map the structure for the Eloquent ORM.

**Update 1:**
I just spotted this:
https://github.com/tuupola/slim-todo-backend/blob/master/app.php

So do i need something like Spot and Fractal together? I wanted to have a central Transformer and not multiple places for output and input. And also i use Eloquent and cant use another ORM...

**Update 2:**
Added Object Model and Mapper Class

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Comment: Can you show `Object` class constructor code?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We can insert it very easily.I did this .I use  slim 3.0 frame work and laravel Eloquent

Here i explain detailed   structure of my project

First you need to install  Eloquent data base driver  and create models

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
include 'dbboot.php';

use User\Models\User;


$app = new \Slim\App([
        'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'debug'               => true,
        'whoops.editor'       => 'sublime',
    ]
]);


$app->get('/user', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $_user = new User();
    $users = $_user->all();
    $payload = [];
    $payload['user']=$users;
    return $response->withStatus(200)->withJson($payload);
});



$app->post('/user', function($request,$response,$args) {
    $_user = new User();
    $user = $request->getParsedBodyParam('userinfo', '');
    $user_id=$_user :: insertGetId($user);
    $payload = [];
    $payload['user_id']=$user_id;
    $payload['message']="Insertion success";
    return $response->withStatus(200)->withJson($payload);

});


// Run app
$app->run();
```

For source code please clone my Github repository:
https://github.com/sherinmac/slim3-with-eloquent.git

Comment: Well you don't use transformers as I do. My data structure is very complex so I need a Transformer.